# Compiler construction and DirectX

Tags: directx, project, gdi, compiler-construction

I am a beginner in the process of designing and coding a project, I already have all the ideas on my head, but I have a problem impeding me of continuing this project.

I feel the code is ugly and unreadable and I cannot continue it this way. The project is a programming language I have on my mind, and it has small graphics capabilities.

Even being beginner, I want to code it using DirectX because everybody wants it. And I want to code it entirely, not depend on any wrapper libraries like SDL.

I did a refactoring of the DirectX module and it exposed all the weaks. There is Direct3D code everywhere, but the code itself does very little! I do not know if this is a fault of my design or a fault of DirectX.

I would start building a project like this using DirectX or I should use just GDI and the Multimedia API of Windows? This is a good progress for a beginner?

Comment: What exactly are these "small graphics capabilities" you're thinking of? What sort of utility do you believe your programming language will have? In what scenarios would it be useful?

Comment: Its only a framebuffer to draw onto. All graphics operations will be compiled in bytecode by the compiler. Its a bit slow, but I think the C VM gets smaller and the confort of writting it in an high level language is worth. Its very flexible to code complex things after. Its a language with the BASIC feel, but with procedures and simple prototyping of objects. After that, when the project is stabilished, I will build a simple GUI for it, like that for PDAs. At the end, platform games like that of 8 bit and pre-16 bit consoles. The idea is to have built at the end a tiny imaginary-computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you've tried to write a compiler without really knowing how it works, and ended up mixing everything together in one big bowl.

You're talking about using DirectX to write the *compiler* - but if you're compiling it to some bytecode, then the compiler shouldn't care whether you'll end up using DirectX, GDI, OpenGL, or something completely different. The *interpreter* needs to care, but if you've abstracted the graphics operations away behind some set of opcodes, then it doesn't really matter what the interpreter uses - you could write an interpreter for each different platform and run the same code.

Compiling is usually easier to do if you use a [multi-step process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler). You may want to consider starting from scratch:

- Make a grammar and write down the semantics for each syntactic construct; not just what each construct does, but what is required for it to do those things (typing rules, etc.). You might find it helpful to look at existing grammars, but it depends on the complexity of your language.
- Write a parser - you can do it by hand or use a [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator), depending on the complexity of your grammar.
- Write code to check your semantic rules.
- Create an instruction set and define a VM, and use your semantics to convert your constructs to instructions (or use something that already exists). You can handle the "external" things (like graphics) by allocating instructions for each thing, or you could define specific addresses which serve as the target of each type of operation (so if you try to call the function at, say, address 0xF000, then the interpreter must execute code to set a specific pixel to some color). The latter approach gives you more flexibility (and means you can use the opcodes for something else), but at the cost of a more complex implemenetation for the CALL instruction - it's up to you to decide what's appropriate for your needs.

When you have your instruction set, you can easily write an interpreter for it, using whatever you want to handle the graphical stuff (DirectX, OpenGL, GDI, SDL...) - it's pretty much just one big switch statement, with the opcodes implemented as the cases. That's where you place the code specific to whatever you use to draw.

If your problem is that you want to combine those two into a single program, so it will read source files and execute them straight away, then you can do that, but it should still help you to keep them separate in your code. The simplest way to do that is probably to first compile it to bytecode, and then just keep it in memory and letting the interpreter read it there.

Note: You should be aware that writing a compiler is not a trivial task. It's not exactly *hard*, either, but there are likely a lot of things which you will have to learn about. Consider reading a book about the topic - the so-called [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)) is considered one of the best out there, if not the best, but other good books exist. When I learned about this stuff a year ago, we used [Concepts of Programmming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136073476) by Robert Sebesta and [Programming Language Processors in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130257869) by David Watt and Deryck Brown. You might want to check your local library to see if they have any of these.

If you want more inspiration, it might help you to look at [the report](https://services.cs.aau.dk/public/tools/library/details.php?id=1243583517) we wrote as part of creating our own programming language at university last year. Ignore the grammar of the language - not only is it a bit buggy, but it's also not serving as a very good example of how you should do it - but the rest of the report might give you some ideas about how to approach the problem.